# PHP/SQL retrieve newly inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am inserting the following data into an SQL table using PHP.

```
    $query1 = 'INSERT INTO log_index_level_1 (LOG_INDEX, LOT_ID, WAFER_ID, MAP_REV, PROBE_DATE) VALUES ("", "' . $LOT_ID . '", "' . $WAFER_ID . '", "' . $MAP_REV. '", ' . "STR_TO_DATE('" . $PROBE_DATE . "', '%m-%d-%Y'" . '))';

    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) 

    echo mysql_result($result1, 0) . "\n;
```

How do I retrieve the first row of the data I just inserted? i.e. I want to `echo` LOG_INDEX.

The above code does not work, since `$result1` returns `1` and not the actual DATA itself.

Comment: first, use PDO. Then you can get `lastInsertId()`, and select data...

Comment: what is the primary key for the log_index_level_1 table ?

Comment: The primary key is `LOG_INDEX`

Comment: Use mysql_insert_id() if you don't like PDOs. However, they are deprecated, so beware. http://php.net/mysql_insert_id

Comment: ^^^ if thats the primary key, you generally want that to be an auto increment column, so it would not be included in the insert, which is the reason you need to use `lastInsertId()` to retrieve it....

Comment: Ok, so I would do `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trend_information', 'root', '' );
` and `$rq = $db->prepare($query1);` then `$db->beginTransaction();` and
then finally `echo $db->lastInsertId();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inspirations.

Here's the code I looked up that solved it.

```
$result_liq = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'log_index_level_1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_liq);
$LOG_INDEX = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code below .

```
<?php

  /*
  ........... your connection code ... etc
  .............
  */

  $query1 = 'INSERT INTO log_index_level_1 (LOG_INDEX, LOT_ID, WAFER_ID, MAP_REV, PROBE_DATE) VALUES ("", "' . $LOT_ID . '", "' . $WAFER_ID . '", "' . $MAP_REV. '", ' . "STR_TO_DATE('" . $PROBE_DATE . "', '%m-%d-%Y'" . '))';

  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

  $query2 = 'select last_insert_id() as lastId';

  $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

  if ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {

    $lastId = $row->lastId;

    $query3 = "select * from log_index_level_1 aa where aa.LOG_INDEX = ".$lastId;

    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);

    if ($lastRow = mysql_fetch_object($result3)) {
      // do something with $lastRow
      // $lastRow->LOT_ID , $lastRow->WAFER_ID ... etc
    }

    mysql_free_result($result3);
  }

  mysql_free_result($result2);
  mysql_free_result($result1);
?>
```